# Python: function returning numbers in ascending order

Tags: python

How can I write a function that would give me a new number in ascending order every time i call it?

For example, if I call it for the first time it returns "1", if I call again, it returns "2".

Comment: You may be interested in the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained

Comment: @syrion: that's "yield explained", probably for now just a mystical way for our friend here to get to his counter ;)

Comment: Yeah, I also upvoted Sven's answer because it's more direct -- but the answer there explains *why* it works. :)

Comment: @syrion: You wouldn't need `yield` to do this -- `counter = iter(xrange(0, 10**100))` would just work fine (the point here being that an explanation of *iterators* would be a more appropriate link than an explanation of *generators*).

Comment: Fair enough; I just tend to think of generators rather than iterators when I think of an infinite series of numbers.

Answer (score 7):

How about `itertools.count()`?

```
counter = itertools.count()
print next(counter)
print next(counter)
print next(counter)
```

prints

```
0
1
2
```

If you want your counter to start from 1, use

```
counter = itertools.count(1)
```

Comment: Trying to use itertools, i get "NameError: name 'itertools' is not defined"

Comment: @Maks: You have to `import itertools` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Thank you. Also, i need those ascending numbers to be assigned to a string. As i udnerstand i cannot use "next" in that case. For example, "ouput = next(counter)" does not work

Comment: "Assigning to a string" does not seem to make any sense.  And `output = next(counter)` will work fine.  If you want to convert an `int` to a string, use `str()`.

Comment: I just get "Global name next is not defined"

Comment: @Maks: In versions of Python older than 2.6, you have to use `counter.next()` instead of `next(counter)`.